# AngularJS: Can't I set a variable value on ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I have a modal that uses ng-show="prefs" to determine visibility.

My desire is to use the close button in the modal to set $scope.prefs to false and to use an anchor tag to set the value to true. However, all I can find on google uses a checkbox rather than anchor tags.

Is there a way to use ng-click to set a variable to false?

Comment: both inside the quotes ... that was what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: I know it's exactly a year later, but you commented on your own answer, not @tymeJV's.... I thought it was funny.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Just do:

```
ng-click="prefs = false"
```

Comment: if i want to set value of two variables, for example: "prefs = false" and "refr = true", then how can i do it? @tymeJV

Comment: @AshokGujjar -- `ng-click="prefs = false; refr = true;"`

Comment: @tymeJV how to change variable value conditionally like if pref is true then only change it to false

Comment: this doesn't work for me, only doing it in the contorller (see msarchets answer) does it. any idea why this could happen?

Comment: @Blauhirn Had the same problem. I dont know why, but when I use an object it works. `ng-click="foobar.prefs = false"`

Comment: @ChristianNilsson -- Probably a scope inheritance issue, read: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes - it's definitely worth it.

Comment: as @tymeJV said it's likely to be a scope issue. Using an object property rather than the scope var straightly fixes this behaviour.

Usually it happens when using ng-repeat as this directive creates a new scope.

Comment: @Ankita you can set it like `ng-click="refr = !prefs"` or `ng-click="refr = prefs == true ? false : true"`

Answer (score 22):

While @tymeJV gave a correct answer, the way to do this to be inline with angular would be:

`ng-click="hidePrefs()"`

and then in your controller:

```
$scope.hidePrefs = function() {  
  $scope.prefs = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some thing like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="" ng-init="btn1=false" ng-init="btn2=false">
    <p>
      <input type="submit" ng-disabled="btn1||btn2" ng-click="btn1=true" ng-model="btn1" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <button ng-disabled="btn1||btn2" ng-model="btn2" ng-click="btn2=true">Click Me!</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latest versions of Angular (2/5/6) :

In your component.ts

```
//x.component.ts
prefs = false;

hidePrefs(){
   this.prefs = true;
}
```